# alternating look and feel in a table view cell

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is it possible to pull in an image for every say 5th row of a tableview from a web server, without upsetting the normal running of the cellforrowatindexpath method? Thanks

Comment: If you mean to ask if you can download an image at runtime for every `nth` row of a table without causing a pause in the load, you would need to pre-cache these images, as download rate on mobile devices is unstable at best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Here is the magic.
    if (!indexPath.row % 5 == 0)
    {
        // Do your usual code
    }
    else
    {
        // Do alternate code (loading background image)
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` if the `indexPath.row` is dividable by 5 and treat the cell differently if true (e.g. other background image, ...).

Comment: Thanks - can you advise me how to do that?